# Updating a table content merging two arrays is possible in one mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say we have an array of ids like: (1,6,3,8,0) submitted by the user, some of those can be or not in a table. An example table could be:

```
id  content
2   ----
3   ----
8   ----
0   ----
```

As you can see 3, 8 and 0 are on the input array and in the table so they must stay on the table, 1 is on the input array but not on the table so it must be added, finally 2 is on the table but no on the input array, so it must be deleted.

I can solve this problem using php but I wonder if i can do this using just a mysql query.

Comment: Any table names, any field names, any queries?

Comment: Of course, you can use for the actual table name giftcode, the input is just a generic text field on the format (number1,number2,number3...) and actually i have no query, Im asking for that, i dont even know if its possible to do everything with mysql

Answer (score 0):

loop through your array do a select count check see if it exists if it doesn't exist ie: count<0 then do an update or replace this will handle the update or insert side of things.
nice and simple

for the delete if not in array do delete from tbl where id NOT IN(array)

hope that makes sense if not let me know I can knock you up an example when I get chance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is an INSERT with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, or possibly an INSERT IGNORE (depending on whether you want to change any values on the table for the items in the array that already exist on the table)